# StateListDrawable is not showing

Tags: android, android-glide

I try to use StateListDrawable R.drawable.image in Glide, but it always show the error R.drawable.default_image. However, if replace R.drawable.image with R.drawable.image_add_sel, it will show normally. Could I know Why?

```
Glide.with(context)                                  
 .load(R.drawable.image)                                 
 .error(R.drawable.default_image)            
 .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)       
 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT) 
 .into(imageView);
```

R.drawable.image is as below:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_add_sel" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_add_sel" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_add_sel" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_add_nor"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just wondering why don't you use,

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: I was using GridView to show photo wall, so I choose Glide to implement it. R.drawable.image was used to show at the last of the GridView. If I use imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image), the imageView will not be shown correctly as the views of GridView reusing and Glide async loading. So I choose the Glide to show the last drawable. But it seems it will throw "This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed" exception.

Comment: It would be better if you could post a bit detail of your problem.